# Encapsulated Link and Controller in Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wan't to program a flexible angular directive with it's properties defined in an own, simple object.

**Angular:**

```
contentFactory.directive("listViewDir", function ($compile) {

return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        datasource: '=',
        config: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        return $scope.config.controller($scope);
    },
    link: 
        return $scope.config.link(scope, element, attrs);
    }
}
```

});

**Own Configuration Object:**

```
contentFactory.controller("indexCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.config = oLiftTabs;})

var configurations = [{
    controller: function ($scope) {

        $scope.ButtonClicked = function () {
            alert('Button wurde geklickt!');
        }

        return $scope;
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs){
        var template = "... myTemplate ..";

        element.html(template);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    },
}]
```

While my solution for the controller works well, it doesn't for the link. 
Is there a more proper way for my approach? Can I realize access in my encapsulated method to the services (like $compile) without declaring it in the directive declaration?

Comment: Where are you defining this 'configuration object'? Controller? Service? Constant? Not sure why you are doing this or what you are hoping to gain. Also, you're missing the first part of the function declaration on your `link` property in the first example, probably a typo.

Comment: The 'configuration object' is a simple plain object. 
My directive has it's template and I want to define the logic in my plain object to interchange it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve? You didn't make it clear where you expect this object to live so I've assumed you want it a parent controller. This doesn't feel like a good idea but without knowing more about your use case it's hard to say.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/bhLjJVSZGSLTaYaHohgS?p=preview)

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <list-view-dir config="config"></list-view-dir>
</body>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {


  $scope.config = {

    controller: function ($scope) {

        $scope.ButtonClicked = function () {
            alert('Button wurde geklickt!');
        }

        return $scope;
    },

    link: function (scope, element, attrs){
        var template = '<button ng-click="ButtonClicked()" > Alert</button>';

        element.html(template);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope); 
    },

  };


});


app.directive("listViewDir", function(){

  return { 

      restrict: "E",

      scope: {
          datasource: '=',
          config: '='
      },

      controller: function ($scope) {
        return $scope.config.controller($scope);
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          return scope.config.link(scope, element, attrs);
      }

  };

});
```

**Update**

From your comments it sounds like you need to use a factory. Maybe something like this? It feels pretty ugly but it could be what you're looking for.

[DEMO2](http://plnkr.co/edit/RjhX8JS3WppewTNJHddT)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('directiveConfigurations', function($compile){

  var configurations = {

    'listViewDir': {

      controller: function ($scope) {

          $scope.ButtonClicked = function(){
              alert('Button wurde geklickt!');
          };

          return $scope;
      },

      link: function (scope, element, attrs){
          var template = '<button ng-click="ButtonClicked()" > Alert</button>';

          element.html(template);
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }

    }

  };


  return {
    get: get
  };
  ////////////////////////

  function get(key){
    return configurations[key];
  }

});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, directiveConfigurations) {

  $scope.config = directiveConfigurations.get('listViewDir');

});


app.directive("listViewDir", function(){

  return { 

      restrict: "E",

      scope: {
          datasource: '=',
          config: '='
      },

      controller: function ($scope) {
        return $scope.config.controller($scope);
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
          return scope.config.link(scope, element, attrs);
      }

  };

});
```

Comment: Ok I found an issue. My configuration object isn't defined directly within the controller, it's assigned there. So I have no access to the services like "$compile". Also do you thing there is a way to define services in my configuration and use them in the controller/link? Unfortunately, it's important for my use case.

Comment: Where is it defined then? Posting all relevant code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts :-) 
What I meant is that I want to define a service in my configuration object in then inject / use it in the controller/link. The config itself is not in a service. It should be completely independent of angular.